# Selenium No encuentra elementos de inicio de sesión en página del SAT

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pruebas-unitarias

Resulta que estoy haciendo pruebas automáticas con Selenium, en la cual requiere que llene los campos de Inicio de sesión, sin embargo no me detecta los campos de RFC y password, ni por ID, selector, xpath ni ninguna otra. Los cuales tienen las propiedades:

- ID= RFC:         #rfc
- ID= Contraseña:  #password

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor mira el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Por favor, añade los ejemplos de codigo con tus intentos y si nos facilitas un enlace para ver el html nos será mas facil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Como te indicaba en mi comentario, es porque se encuentra dentro de un iframe:

[image: Iframe a la vista]

Debes cambiar al iframe antes de buscar los elementos, como no indicas con que lenguaje estas trabajando te pongo el ejemplo de como se haria en Java:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameCentro");
// Cuando termines todas las acciones sobre este frame debes volver al original
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```